# HTML 5: how to make stackable images?

Tags: html

Is it possible to load up 10 images (same dimension), stack them on top of one another only showing 1 image at a time and then by holding down the left mouse button and dragging the mouse up you scroll in one direction and moving the mouse down scrolls in the opposite direction?'

if so how can this be done? canvas element would be the begining, no?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for... Javascript!

This solution isn't perfect, but it's an example of mouse scrolling images: https://github.com/kamranayub/Just-Another-Carousel